# Trac: change ticket count per page in report

Tags: trac

In Trac, by default, the the number of tickets per page in a report is 100. Is it possible to increase this count? How? Could I do this in the SQL query? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the  `trac.ini` configuration file: just configure

```
[report]
items_per_page = <your_item_count_per_page>
```

Comment: It's always when you think " 'lready spent too much time searching over the net, let's make some crowdsourcing" that the answer comes by itself...